# Multivariable Optimization Rectangular Box Volume

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

What are the dimensions for the cheapest possible rectangular box with a volume of $490 cm^3$  if the material for the bottom costs $\$6/cm^2$, material for the sides costs $\$7/cm^2$, and material for the top costs $\$14/cm^2$ ?

I can't seem to get anywhere close to the answer in $x,y,z$ form.

Comment: You may want to provide the formulas you have come up with in terms of $x,y,z$, i.e., formulas for volume and so on.  Also it seems the material for the sides cost zero?  I suspect there should be a nonzero cost for the material on the sides...

Comment: @amd That problem mentions a square base, but this problem doesn't.

Comment: @browngreen Good point. The other problem is a single-variable optimization.

Comment: @browngreen Then again, by symmetry the optimal solution is going to have a square bottom, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume = $x y z = 490$.

Cost = $\underbrace{6 x y}_{\rm bottom} + \underbrace{14 x y}_{\rm top} + 7 (\underbrace{2 x z}_{\rm front\ and\ back} + \underbrace{2 y z}_{\rm left\ and\ right}) = 20 x y + 14 z (x + y)$.

Now, minimize the cost, given the constraint of volume by taking the derivative of the cost with respect to $x$, setting it to zero.  (The $z$ can be eliminated algebraically and we'll use the symmetry of $x$ and $y$.)

${\partial C \over \partial x} = {6860 \over x y} + 20 y - {6860 (x+y) \over x^2 y}$.

Set to zero and find $x = {7 \sqrt{7} \over \sqrt{y}}$.

Note that all the equations are symmetric with respect to the interchange $x \leftrightarrow y$.  After all, there's no difference mathematically between left-right and front-back.  So $x^{3/2} = 7 \sqrt{7}$:

Finally:  $x = y = 7$ and $z = 10$.

Comment: So i've gotten to this point but when i find the derivative in terms of x and y and set one to 0 i am getting huge decimals which can't be right